# Why does named union inside struct overwriting other struct members?

Tags: c++, struct, unions

```
struct TestStruct
{   
    int a;
    int b;

    union
    {
        char c[2];
        int d;
    };
};

TestStruct instance;
```

If I do

```
instance.a = 100; 
instance.b = 200; 
instance.d = 300;
```

everything's fine.

But, If I give union a name:

```
struct TestStruct
{   
    int a;
    int b;

    union ZZZ // Note here!!
    {
        char c[2];
        int d;
    };
};

TestStruct instance;
```

And I do same things again:

```
instance.a = 100;
instance.b = 200;
instance.ZZZ::d = 300;
```

then

```
instance.ZZZ::d = 300;
```

is overwriting `instance.a` to be `300`, why?!

Additionally, I can not see the union members in debugger watch list if it has a name.

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: With the name, `ZZZ` is not a data member of `TestStruct`, it's a nested class (that is to say, it's a union whose only relation to `TestStruct` is that it just so happens to be defined in its namespace). There is no such place as `instance.ZZZ::d`. I don't understand why the compiler lets you write `instance.ZZZ::d = 300;`, but I don't have MSVC to check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you name the union there is no longer a data member in the class corresponding to `d` so `instance.ZZZ::d = 300;` doesn't mean anything. (With VS2012 I get "error C2039: 'ZZZ' : is not a member of 'TestStruct'")

To have a member of a union type you'll have to give it a name.

```
struct TestStruct
{   
    int a;
    int b;

    union ZZZ // Note here!!
    {
        char c[2];
        int d;
    } z;
};

instance.a = 100;
instance.b = 200;
instance.z.d = 300;
```

C++ has a special rule for 'anonymous unions', where an unnamed union type of the form `union {` *`member-specification`* `};` also creates an unnamed object. The names of the union's members are injected into the enclosing scope and access the unnamed object's members.

That's what you're getting when you don't name the union type inside your class. But as soon as you give the type a name the union no longer matches that special rule and there's no longer an unnamed union member in the class; You then have to add the union data member normally, by naming the member variable.